# Designing multivariate density plot in R

Tags: r, tikz

I saw an appealing multivariate density plot using Tikz and was wondering if there was a way to replicate this plot with my own data within R. I am not familiar with Tikz, but I found this reference which seems to imply I may be able to use this feature within R. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tikzdevice-demo/

In short, what is the best way to produce a plot very similar (different distribution of course) to the one shown below using the two data samples provided?

Here is some sample data that can be used to create the distribution plot.

```
# Sample data
var1 <- exp(rlnorm(100000, meanlog=0.03, sdlog=0.15))/100
var2 <- 1-(var1 + rnorm(100000, 0, 0.01))
```

Here is the reference page where I found the original chart

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31708/draw-a-bivariate-normal-distribution-in-tikz

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could start with the `persp` function to draw the 3 dimensional plot (if you do this from data rather than the formula then you need to use some form of density estimation first, the example plot looks smooth enough that it is probably based on the formula rather than estimated from the data).  Then use the return value from `persp` to project the additional plotting info.

There may also be an option using the rgl package, I seem to remember that it has a way to project a plot onto the axes planes.

**Edit**

Here is some sample code to get you started.  It uses a parametric distribution, but could be adapted to use `kde2d` from MASS or other ways of estimating the density from data:

```
x <- seq( -3, 3, length=25 )
y <- seq( -3, 3, length=25 )

z <- outer( x, y, function(x,y) dnorm(x,0,0.5)*dnorm(y,0,1) )
zl <- c(0,4*max(z))

## persp plot
trmat <- persp(x,y,z, theta=120, zlim=zl, box=FALSE, shade=0.5)

## x grid
for( i in seq(-3,3, by=0.5 ) ) {
    lines( trans3d( c(i,i), c(-3,-3), zl, trmat ), col='grey' )
}
for( i in seq(0,zl[2], length=7) ) {
    lines( trans3d( c(-3,3), c(-3,-3), c(i,i), trmat ), col='grey' )
}

## marginal for x

lines( trans3d( seq(-3,3,length=100), -3, dnorm(seq(-3,3,length=100),0,.5), 
    trmat), lwd=2, col='blue' )

## y grid
for( i in seq(-3,3, by=0.5 ) ) {
    lines( trans3d( c(-3,-3), c(i,i), zl, trmat ), col='grey' )
}
for( i in seq(0,zl[2], length=7) ) {
    lines( trans3d( c(-3,-3), c(-3,3), c(i,i), trmat ), col='grey' )
}

## marginal for y

lines( trans3d( -3, seq(-3,3,length=100), dnorm(seq(-3,3,length=100),0,1), 
    trmat), lwd=2, col='blue' )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I updated the sample code to include an extra random component to var2.

Comment: Hi Greg -- Great answer. I just added an image of the plot produced by your code, and deleted the first sentence, which only made sense before the OP updated their sample data. Hope you don't mind.